# ZEIT NOW variable secrets

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm looking for a way to refer to a different set of secrets(env variables) depending on the value of another env variable.

i.e.
`if (process.env.STAGE === "test") return config = process.env.TEST_CONFIG`

I know that with automated github deployments there are [included env variables](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/advanced/now-for-github/)

But how do I reference them correctly? For example:

`const config = process.env.NOW_GITHUB_COMMIT_REF === 'master' ? prod : dev;`

Doesn't work for me.

(`NOW_GITHUB_COMMIT_REF`:
The branch that the app was deployed using.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just duplicate my answer here from Spectrum.

Folder structure:

```sh
config/
    dev.json
    test.json
    prod.json
    index.js
api/
    search.js
```

*config/index.js*

```js
const devConfig = require('../config/dev');
const testConfig = require('../config/test');
const prodConfig = require('../config/prod');

const { NOW_GITHUB_COMMIT_REF } = process.env;
if (NOW_GITHUB_COMMIT_REF === 'test') 
  return testConfig;
else if (NOW_GITHUB_COMMIT_REF === 'master') 
  return prodConfig;
else
  return devConfig;
```

*api/search.js*

```js
const config = require('../config');
```

In that case, `master` branch gets prod config, `test` branch - test config, all other branches - dev config.